# Recover root access after wrong usermod -g in Ubuntu 14

Tags: security, sudo, user-accounts

I have to recover root access to an Ubuntu 14 box where there is only a single local user and `usermod -g somegroup ...` has been executed instead of `usermod -G ...` so the user can't sudo anymore.

I am aware I can boot with a live distro, mount local volume and chroot into the system to change /etc/group but I was wondering if there is a smoothest solution. Ubuntu is running on bare metal. I have physical access to the server and it can be shutdown in a scheduled maintenance window.

Regarding the solution I am aware of, I'm not sure how to perform it because the system has / volume on an mdadm raid 1 array and the live distro would see disks as standalone sata devices.

Any clarification or any other possible solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Nothing stops you from creating a software/mdadm RAID on a live cd/dvd and then mounting and chrooting to it.

Comment: I got how to do it on a sw raid. Should I assume this is the best solution for this situation?

Comment: A live distro should recognize and assemble a software RAID. If it doesn't, use a different live distro.